# To combine filtering conditions in Pandas, use bitwise operators ('&' and '|') not pure Python ones ('and' and 'or')

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Подскажите, где налажал?

Задача: из датасета взять некие параметры каждого наблюдения и при наступлении условий в функции создать для каждого наблюдения новый признак

```
def luxury_tax(df):
    conditions = [
        ((df['name'] == 'M240i xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))  # 1.1
        | ((df['name'] == 'M235i xDrive') & (df['model_age'] == 1) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000) & (df['body_type'] <= 'coupe'))
        | ((df['name'] == '330d xDrive') & (df['model_age'] == 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M340i xDrive') & (df['model_age'] == 1) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '340i xDrive') & (df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000))
        | ((df['name'] == '330i xDrive') & (df['model_age'] == 1) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000))
        | ((df['name'] == '340i xDrive') & (1 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000) & (df['body_type'] <= 'liftback_gran_turismo'))
        | ((df['name'] == '430i') & (df['model_age'] == 1) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000) & (df['body_type'] <= 'coupe'))
        | ((df['name'] == '430i xDrive') & (1 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000) & (df['body_type'] <= 'cabriolet'))
        | ((df['name'] == '430i') & (1 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000) & (df['body_type'] <= 'cabriolet'))
        | ((df['name'] == '420d') & (df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000) & (df['body_type'] <= 'cabriolet'))
        | ((df['name'] == '430i xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000) & (df['body_type'] <= 'coupe'))
        | ((df['name'] == '440i xDrive') & (1 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000) & (df['body_type'] <= 'coupe'))
        | ((df['name'] == '440i') & (1 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000) & (df['body_type'] <= 'cabriolet'))
        | ((df['name'] == '520i') & (df['model_age'] == 1) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000))
        | ((df['name'] == '520d') & (df['model_age'] == 1) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000))
        | ((df['name'] == '520d xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000))
        | ((df['name'] == '530d xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '530i') & (df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000))
        | ((df['name'] == '530i xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000))
        | ((df['name'] == '540i xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '630d xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '630i') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000))
        | ((df['name'] == '640d xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '640i xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '730i') & (df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline'))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M2') & (df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M2 Competition') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M550d xDrive') & (1 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M550i xDrive') & (df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M40i') & (df['series'] <= 'X3') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M40d') & (df['series'] <= 'X3') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '20d xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X3') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 3) (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '20i xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X3') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000))
        | ((df['name'] == '30i xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X3') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000))
        | ((df['name'] == '30d xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X3') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M40i') & (df['series'] <= 'X4') & (df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M40d') & (df['series'] <= 'X4') & (df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '20i xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X4') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000))
        | ((df['name'] == '20d xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X4') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000))
        | ((df['name'] == '20i xDrive M Sport') & (df['series'] <= 'X4') & (df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000))
        | ((df['name'] == '28i xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X4') & (df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000))
        | ((df['name'] == '30i xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X4') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000))
        | ((df['name'] == '30d xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X4') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '35d xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X4') & (df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '35i xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X4') & (df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '25d xDrive Business') & (df['series'] <= 'X5') & (df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '30d xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X5') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '35i xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X5') & (df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '40i xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X5') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '40d xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X5') & (df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '40e xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X5') & (df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'hybrid'))
        | ((df['name'] == '50i xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X5') & (df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500))
        | ((df['name'] == '30d xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X6') & (df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '20i sDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'Z4') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000))
        | ((df['name'] == '30i sDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'Z4') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M40i') & (df['series'] <= 'Z4') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M4') & (1 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000) & (df['body_type'] == 'coupe'))
        | ((df['name'] == '120Ah') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'electro'))
        | ((df['name'] == '620d xDrive') & (df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000)),
        ((df['name'] == 'М4') & (df['model_age'] <= 1) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))  # 2
        | ((df['name'] == 'М') & (df['series'] <= 'X3') & (df['model_age'] <= 1) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M40d') & (df['series'] <= 'X4') & (df['model_age'] <= 1) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M40i') & (df['series'] <= 'X4') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M') & (df['series'] <= 'X4') & (df['model_age'] <= 1) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '640i xDrive') & (df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000) & (df['body_type'] == 'cabriolet'))
        | ((df['name'] == '640i') & (df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000) & (df['body_type'] == 'cabriolet'))
        | ((df['name'] == '650i xDrive') & (2 < df['model_age'] <= 5) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500) & (df['body_type'] == 'coupe'))
        | ((df['name'] == '650i xDrive') & (2 < df['model_age'] <= 5) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500) & (df['body_type'] == 'cabriolet'))
        | ((df['name'] == '650i xDrive') & (2 < df['model_age'] <= 5) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500) & (df['body_type'] == 'coupe'))
        | ((df['name'] == '650i') & (2 < df['model_age'] <= 5) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500) & (df['body_type'] == 'cabriolet'))
        | ((df['name'] == '730i') & (df['model_age'] <= 1) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000))
        | ((df['name'] == '730d xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 5) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '730Ld xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 5) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '740d xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 5) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '740Ld xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 5) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '740Le xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 4) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'hybrid') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 2000))
        | ((df['name'] == '740Li xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 4) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '750d xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 4) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '750i xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 5) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500))
        | ((df['name'] == '750Ld xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 4) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '750Li xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 5) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M550d xDrive') & (df['model_age'] <= 1) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M550i xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M5') & (2 < df['model_age'] <= 5) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500) & (df['body_type'] == 'sedan'))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M5 Competition') & (1 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M6') & (3 < df['model_age'] <= 5) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500) & (df['body_type'] == 'coupe'))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M6') & (df['model_age'] <= 4) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500) & (df['body_type'] == 'cabriolet'))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M6') & (2 < df['model_age'] <= 5) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500) & (df['body_type'] == 'coupe'))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M760Li xDrive') & (df['model_age'] <= 4) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 7000))
        | ((df['name'] == '50i xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X5') & (df['model_age'] == 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M') & (df['series'] <= 'X5') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 5) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M50i') & (df['series'] <= 'X5') & (df['model_age'] <= 1) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M50d') & (df['series'] <= 'X5') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M50d xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X5') & (df['model_age'] <= 4) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '30d xDrive Exclusive') & (df['series'] <= 'X5') & (df['model_age'] <= 4) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '30d xDrive Pure Experience') & (df['series'] <= 'X5') & (df['model_age'] <= 4) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '40d xDrive M Sport') & (df['series'] <= 'X5') & (3 < df['model_age'] <= 5) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '35i xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X6') & (df['model_age'] == 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '40i xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X6') & (df['model_age'] <= 1) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '30d xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X6') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M') & (df['series'] <= 'X6') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 5) & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M50i') & (df['series'] <= 'X6') & (df['model_age'] <= 1) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M50d') & (df['series'] <= 'X6') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M50d xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X6') & (df['model_age'] <= 4) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '30d xDrive Luxury') & (df['series'] <= 'X6') & (df['model_age'] <= 4) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '30d xDrive M Sport') & (df['series'] <= 'X6') & (df['model_age'] <= 4) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '30d xDrive Pure Extravagance') & (df['series'] <= 'X6') & (df['model_age'] <= '4') & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '40d xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X6') & (1 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '40d xDrive M Sport') & (df['series'] <= 'X6') & (df['model_age'] <= 4) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '50i xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X6') & (1 < df['model_age'] <= 4) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500))
        | ((df['name'] == '30d xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X7') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '40i xDrive') & (df['series'] <= 'X7') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M50d') & (df['series'] <= 'X7') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000))
        | ((df['name'] == '840i xDrive') & (df['model_age'] == 1) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000) & (df['body_type'] == 'cabriolet'))
        | ((df['name'] == '840i xDrive') & (df['model_age'] == 1) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000) & (df['body_type'] == 'coupe'))
        | ((df['name'] == '840d xDrive') & (df['model_age'] == 1) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000) & (df['body_type'] == 'coupe'))
        | ((df['name'] == '840d xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'diesel') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000) & (df['body_type'] == 'coupe'))
        | ((df['name'] == '840i xDrive') & (df['model_age'] == 1) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 3000) & (df['body_type'] == 'coupe'))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M850i xDrive') & (df['model_age'] == 1) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500) & (df['body_type'] == 'coupe'))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M850i xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500) & (df['body_type'] == 'coupe'))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M850i xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500) & (df['body_type'] == 'cabriolet'))
        | ((df['name'] == 'i8') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'hybrid') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 1500) & (df['body_type'] == 'coupe')),
        ((df['name'] == 'M8') & (df['model_age'] == 1) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500) & (df['body_type'] == 'coupe'))  # 3
        | ((df['name'] == 'M8') & (df['model_age'] == 1) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 4500) & (df['body_type'] == 'cabriolet'))
        | ((df['name'] == 'i8') & (2 < df['model_age'] <= 4) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'hybrid') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 1500))
        | ((df['name'] == 'i8') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 2) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'hybrid') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 1500) & (df['body_type'] == 'roadster'))
        | ((df['name'] == 'M760Li xDrive') & (0 < df['model_age'] <= 3) & (df['fuel_type'] == 'gasoline') & (df['engine_displacement'] <= 6600) & (df['body_type'] == 'roadster')),
    ]
    choices = [1.1,2,3]
    df['luxury_tax'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=1)
    return df['luxury_tax']

new_big_df['luxury_tax'] = luxury_tax(new_big_df)
```

Выдает ошибку:

To combine filtering conditions in Pandas, use bitwise operators ('&' and '|') not pure Python ones ('and' and 'or')

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Не могу найти, где налажал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю проблема вот в таких конструкциях:

```
(0 < df['model_age'] <= 2)
```

Насколько я понимаю, это "синтаксический сахар", который переводится питоном в такую конструкцию:

```
(0 < df['model_age'] and df['model_age'] <= 2)
```

Тут то и появляются вдруг `and/or` "обычного питона", на которые и ругается `Pandas`.

А вообще я бы вам рекомендовал не делать такие простыни кода копипастой, а написать некую функцию, которая будет вам проверять эти условия по переданным в неё параметрам. Это же невозможно читать вообще. Что-то типа:

```
check_conditions('M240i xDrive', [0, 2], 'gasoline', 3000) |
...
```

Это в первом приближении, дальше можно ещё более свернуть это всё в некий доменный язык.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

Comment: Сама по себе рекомендация (0 < df['model_age'] and df['model_age'] <= 2) оказалась верной.

Comment: Вы правы по поводу того, что это сложно читать. Хотелось на скорую руку проверить саму гипотезу с новым параметром. Если подойдет, тогда оптимизирую код.

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk Если совет помог, отметьте ответ как верный, где-то должна быть такая галочка. А что касается проверки гипотезы - неужели для этого надо было столько условий писать? Обычно гипотезы как-то попроще проверяют )

Comment: отметил. я только учусь data science, поэтому многие вещи делаю коряво